# Кириллица в Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby

При вводе текста (через `gets.chomp`) у меня выводит ошибку

Есть пример:

```
a = gets.chomp
```

Ввожу `Привет`

```
#=> Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError occured "\x8F" on UTF-8
```

P.S. если что перед этим уже используется

```
require 'dl' 
require 'zlib'
require 'single_byte'
require 'utf_16_32'
require 'japanese_sjis'
require 'Win32API '
```

Дополнительно:

```
gets.chomp.bytes.to_a # => [143, 224,168, 162, 165, 226] (для "Привет")
```

Дело происходит не в голом MRI, а в RGSS. Возможно, он накладывает какие-то ограничения?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, [минимальный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), на котором воспроизводится проблема. Полагаю, в вашем случае это будет либо просто `a = gets.chomp`, либо включение каких-то библиотек (тогда подберите минимальное количество библиотек) и `a = gets.chomp`.

Comment: Добавьте трейс. И это происходит в `irb`, или просто при запуске отдельного файла с кодом тоже?

Comment: @D-side показать не могу, потому что используется игровой движок с таким языком (это объясняет почему я использую только v1.9.2)

Немного подробностей: После ввода "Привет" в `a = gets.chomp` `a` имеет значение `\x8F?\xA5\xE2` вместо `Привет` [скриншот](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/313337053452435458/317741827526754314/unknown.png).

Comment: Хм. Непрямая отладка. Приключе-е-ения. Ладно. Попробуйте вывести `gets.chomp.bytes`, давайте посмотрим что он всё-таки считывает.

Comment: @D-side `gets.chomp.bytes` получил  `#<Enumerator:0x75031e0>`

Comment: Ок, а теперь на нём `.to_a`?

Comment: @D-side [143, 224,168, 162, 165, 226]

Comment: Вот мы и вышли на проблему. Кириллица ввелась по одному байту на символ. Это действительно **не** UTF-8.

Comment: @D-side однако по таблице символов `Alt+` все совпадает.

Comment: Потому что там тоже не UTF-8.

Comment: К сожалению, у меня нет возможности быстро воспроизвести вашу ситуацию, т. к. у вас, по всей видимости, дело под Windows происходит. Но попробуйте в начале программы сделать `$stdin.set_encoding('cp866')` и повторите ваши опыты.

Comment: @D-side Не помогло

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59500/discussion-between-d-side-and-zeka10000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По итогам [долгой дискуссии](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/59500) мы выяснили, что в RGSS очень печально с поддержкой кодировок. Настолько, что кодировок там всего 4, и ни одна из них не соответствует тому, что реально вводится из `$stdin`. А там CP866, обычный для консолей в Windows.

Придётся написать перекодировщик в UTF-8 самостоятельно. К счастью, сделать это несложно. Вот один вариант:

```
class AutonomousCP866
  # Байты строки UTF-8 из 256 символов, всех символов из CP866 по порядку
  CHARS = [
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 208, 144, 208, 145, 208, 146, 208, 147, 208, 148, 208, 149, 208, 150, 208, 151, 208, 152, 208, 153, 208, 154, 208, 155, 208, 156, 208, 157, 208, 158, 208, 159, 208, 160, 208, 161, 208, 162, 208, 163, 208, 164, 208, 165, 208, 166, 208, 167, 208, 168, 208, 169, 208, 170, 208, 171, 208, 172, 208, 173, 208, 174, 208, 175, 208, 176, 208, 177, 208, 178, 208, 179, 208, 180, 208, 181, 208, 182, 208, 183, 208, 184, 208, 185, 208, 186, 208, 187, 208, 188, 208, 189, 208, 190, 208, 191, 226, 150, 145, 226, 150, 146, 226, 150, 147, 226, 148, 130, 226, 148, 164, 226, 149, 161, 226, 149, 162, 226, 149, 150, 226, 149, 149, 226, 149, 163, 226, 149, 145, 226, 149, 151, 226, 149, 157, 226, 149, 156, 226, 149, 155, 226, 148, 144, 226, 148, 148, 226, 148, 180, 226, 148, 172, 226, 148, 156, 226, 148, 128, 226, 148, 188, 226, 149, 158, 226, 149, 159, 226, 149, 154, 226, 149, 148, 226, 149, 169, 226, 149, 166, 226, 149, 160, 226, 149, 144, 226, 149, 172, 226, 149, 167, 226, 149, 168, 226, 149, 164, 226, 149, 165, 226, 149, 153, 226, 149, 152, 226, 149, 146, 226, 149, 147, 226, 149, 171, 226, 149, 170, 226, 148, 152, 226, 148, 140, 226, 150, 136, 226, 150, 132, 226, 150, 140, 226, 150, 144, 226, 150, 128, 209, 128, 209, 129, 209, 130, 209, 131, 209, 132, 209, 133, 209, 134, 209, 135, 209, 136, 209, 137, 209, 138, 209, 139, 209, 140, 209, 141, 209, 142, 209, 143, 208, 129, 209, 145, 208, 132, 209, 148, 208, 135, 209, 151, 208, 142, 209, 158, 194, 176, 226, 136, 153, 194, 183, 226, 136, 154, 226, 132, 150, 194, 164, 226, 150, 160, 194, 160
  ].pack("C*").force_encoding('utf-8').freeze
  # в строку, сообщить что это UTF-8 и заморозить, т. к. это константа

  def self.to_utf8(string)
    string.bytes.each_with_object("") do |byte, buffer|
      buffer << CHARS[byte]
    end
  end
end
```

Как использовать, очевидно из определения: `AutonomousCP866.to_utf8(gets.chomp)`. Вероятно, можно угореть и сделать monkeypatch для стандартных функций ввода, но я бы поостерёгся.

Значения для массива выше получены на обычном MRI следующим образом:

```
(0..255).flat_map do |byte| # Для номеров 0-255 (включительно) склеить вместе:
  byte.chr('cp866')    # Взять символ с этим номером из CP866
      .encode('utf-8') # Преобразовать в UTF-8
      .bytes           # Получить последовательность байт в нём
end.join(", ") # ... и причесать для вставки в код

# Однострочник
(0..255).flat_map { |byte| byte.chr('cp866').encode('utf-8').bytes }.join(", ")
```